# Annotation for DataSize validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, bean-validation

Is there any standard validator annotation I can use for a [`DataSize`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/unit/DataSize.html) field?

Something like javax `@Min` and `@Max`, or [Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-defineconstraints-hv-constraints)'s `@DurationMin` and `@DurationMax`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For class `DataSize`, there's no standard validator, so you should implement your own. But it's quite easy :)

Annotation interface:

```
import org.springframework.util.unit.DataUnit;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = DataSizeMaxValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DataSizeMax {

    String message() default "must be less than or equal to {value} {unit}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    long value();

    DataUnit unit();
}
```

Validator:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

@Component
public class DataSizeMaxValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DataSizeMax, DataSize> {
    private DataSize dataSizeMax;

    @Override
    public void initialize(DataSizeMax dataSizeMax) {
        this.dataSizeMax = DataSize.of(dataSizeMax.value(), dataSizeMax.unit());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(DataSize value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return dataSizeMax.compareTo(value) >= 0;
    }
}
```

That's it. Then use this annotation as here:

```
import pizza.nikiforov.validators.DataSizeMax;
import org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize;
import org.springframework.util.unit.DataUnit;

public class Data {

    @DataSizeMax(value = 15L, unit = DataUnit.MEGABYTES)
    private DataSize dataSize;

    // other fields
    // constructors, getters and setters
}
```